# How to change the uib-typeahead array based on button choice?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to change the array that the uib-typeahead uses for the autocomplete on a search field. I have a button that chooses the categories to search by name, title, education, expertise and the button is working to filter the search results. But I am having issues trying to do the same thing for the uib-typeahead autocomplete.

I have a few arrays that pull the correct information and if I put them in and publish the page it works as intended, but I can't get them to switch out dynamically when a new filter is chosen.

The arrays that I am using. The default is the searchText with every category included. I tested them all and if I switch out searchText for any other one it works fine.

```
$scope.searchText = []; // all text that will be searched
$scope.searchname = []; // Name text that will be searched
$scope.searchtitle = []; // Title text that will be searched
$scope.searchexpertise = []; // Expertise text that will be searched
$scope.searcheducation = []; // Education text that will be searched
$scope.searchpositionsHeld = []; // PositionsHeld text that will be searched
```

Here are my button and input sections.

```
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline dropdown-toggle rounded-0" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span id="search_selection">Search by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="changeFilterTo('name'); changeSearchTo('$scope.searchname')" href="#name">Name</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="changeFilterTo('title'); changeSearchTo('$scope.searchtitle')" href="#title">Title</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="changeFilterTo('tags'); changeSearchTo('$scope.searchtags')" href="#tags">Lab Capability</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="changeFilterTo('expertise'); changeSearchTo('$scope.searchexpertise')" href="#expertise">Expertise</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="changeFilterTo('education'); changeSearchTo('$scope.searcheducation')" href="#education">Education</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="changeFilterTo('positionsHeld'); changeSearchTo('$scope.searchpositionsHeld')" href="#positionsHeld">LANL Positions</a>

                    </ul>
                </div>

            <input
                class="form-control"
                id="search_param"
                placeholder="Type something"
                type="text"
                ng-model="search[filter]"
                uib-typeahead="item for item in searchText | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:25"
                ng-change="changeHandler()"
            />
```

And here is what I was trying to set out the uib-typeahead attribute.

```
$scope.changeSearchTo = function(pr) {
$scope.searchText = [];    
$scope.searchText = pr;
}
```

So far nothing I have tried can switch out the arrays and I have tried searching for more answers, but nothing seems to match. I appreciate the help anyone can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

remove `$scope` in the template. Try `changeSearchTo(searchname)` without the comma.

Comment: Hi Merlin, thank you for the response! I gave that a shot and the autocomplete was still giving back the full results of searchText no filtering. With the above code it was working on the searchText to pull all the results no filtering, then when I would choose a filter it would return the first letter as an auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

Merlin was mostly correct I removed $scope and then used this code to set the attribute:

```
    $scope.changeSearchTo = function(prs) {
    $scope.searchText = [];    
    $scope.searchText = $scope[prs];
}
```